# Can't override margin on <h#> tags?

Tags: html, css

Good day to all of you...

This has been bugging me for quite a while and I've wasted precious time on this... it's irritating me as hell.

Couldn't get rid of the left side margin on the h1 (etc) tags... So right now I don't think it's the html... Take a look at the screenshot.

http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/415/screendn.jpg

You can see that Arial has the biggest margin of them all. Impact is perfect. Is this already known to every designer out there? Better yet, does it have to be like my screenshot?

I've included a reset.css, I tried * { }. I checked it out in IE, Chrome and Firefox, all the same. Chrome gives it a -webkit-margin-before of 0.67em... It's bugging me, because a 1 pixel offset drives me crazy!

**Like Darek said, it could be a font related problem, but I wanted to be sure!**

Thanks in advance, Marvin.

Comment: Trying to assert this level of pixel control on the web is MADNESS.

Comment: Madness? This is WEBDESIGN! Maybe a bit overboard indeed... I know.

Comment: @Mathletics i actually had a design which suffered from 1px shift (400px high white line on black bg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but I don't believe this is a margin issue...it's simply the way the font is designed.

I guess if it's really bugging you, you could always go with a hacky negative margin solution?

Comment: Thanks, Darek. What you said. I just wanted to be sure.

Edit: Yes, I was thinking about a negative margin. I will be adding a few lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

The kerning in the Arial font is the problem- as said before this is mostly in the way the font is designed.

You can remedy this problem a bit by slightly decreasing the letter-spacing attribute of the styles that use this font in your CSS, like `letter-spacing: -0.05em;` . The side effect is that all the letters will be more slightly grouped together, but that's the best approach I can think of.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

At first I thought something was wrong with my code but then I tried a different font and the problem was gone. 

Still weird that Chrome shows a user agent stylesheet when I inspect Arial, but when I inspect Impact it doesn't show one. Then again, I guess that has to do with the font and or kerning.

I will be adding a few lines of code. Thanks again.

Comment: maybe add this style only on `:first-letter`